# Hide/Show Buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a button for each picture that will hide the other two. For example if I click the button for the left image, the left image will show and it will hide the middle and right pictures.  HTML needs to stay the same, any suggestions?

```
<div id="works">
    <figure data-artist="left">
            <img src="david.jpg" alt>
        <figcaption>left image</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure data-artist="middle">
        <img src="david-plaster.jpg" alt>
        <figcaption>middle image</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure data-artist="right">
        <img src="florence-cathedral.jpg" alt>
        <figcaption>Right image</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>

<div id="controls">

</div>

<script>
    var hideShowButton = document.getElementById("hideShowButton");

    hideShowButton.onclick = function() { 
        var allImages = { left: "left", center: "middle", right: "right" };

        if(document.getElementById("michelangelo").style.visibility == 'visible') {
            for (var image in allImages) {
                document.getElementById(allImages[image]).style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
            }
            document.getElementById("hideShowButton").innerHTML = "Hide";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById(allImages[image])` will not fetch any elements - a) this method expects a string, b) it only returns a single element, and c) in any case there are no images with the IDs contained within the allImages object, so even if the method would accept an arbitrary object like this, it would fail to find anything. Try using document.querySelectorAll, and giving the images a class that they all share. Then you can hide the elements with that class, and re-show the specific one that you want. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: Don't remove the original question, otherwise it won't help other people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

- When the button inside div `controls` is clicked, he execute the function `showImage()`.
- This function get all figure elements and set a display as none.
- Then we get the attribute `data-artist` of the element that trigger the function, that is the same as the figure, and add a display style as block on the figure that has the same attribute `data-artist` that the element.

  ```js
  function showImage(event){
    var objClass = event.getAttribute("data-artist");
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("figure");
    for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i++)
      elems[i].style.display = 'none';
    
    var element = document.querySelector('figure[data-artist='+objClass+']');
    element.style.display = 'block';
    
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>  
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="works">
  <figure data-artist="left">
      <img src="david.jpg" alt>
      <figcaption>left image</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure data-artist="middle">
      <img src="david-plaster.jpg" alt>
      <figcaption>middle image</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure data-artist="right">
      <img src="florence-cathedral.jpg" alt>
      <figcaption>Right image</figcaption>
  </figure>
  </div>

  <div id="controls">
    <button data-artist="left" onclick="showImage(this);">left</button>
    <button data-artist="middle" onclick="showImage(this);">center</button>
    <button data-artist="right" onclick="showImage(this);">right</button>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Comment: doesnt look like hes using jquery

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Comment: Sorry, i'll never make such thing again in my life.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="works">
<figure data-artist="left">
<img src="david.jpg" id="image1" alt>
<figcaption>left image</figcaption>
<button onclick="hideshow('1');">Choose</button>
</figure>

<figure data-artist="middle">
<img src="david-plaster.jpg" id="image2" alt>
<figcaption>middle image</figcaption>
<button onclick="hideshow('2');">Choose</button>
</figure>

<figure data-artist="right">
<img src="florence-cathedral.jpg" id="image3" alt>
<figcaption>Right image</figcaption>
 <button onclick="hideshow('3');">Choose</button>
</figure>
</div>

<div id="controls">

</div>
<script>

function hideshow(buttonpressed) {
      var img1 = document.getElementById("image1");
      var img2 = document.getElementById("image2");
      var img3 = document.getElementById("image3");

     if(buttonpressed==1) {
            img1.style.visibility == 'visible';
            img2.style.visibility == 'hidden';
            img3.style.visibility == 'hidden';
      }

     if(buttonpressed==2) {
            img1.style.visibility == 'hidden';
            img2.style.visibility == 'visible';
            img3.style.visibility == 'hidden';
     }


     if(buttonpressed==3) {
            img1.style.visibility == 'hidden';
            img2.style.visibility == 'hidden';
            img3.style.visibility == 'visible';
     }

}

</script>
```

If there will be many buttons (not 3), approach would be different than this

Hope this helps